# How to set sigmask and do a long jump atomically in my signal handler?

Tags: c, signals, scheduler, coroutine, ucontext

I am implementing a coroutine scheduler. A thread is interrupted(by `SIGURG`) regularly to make a switch. I am using `swapcontext`(from `ucontext.h`) in sighandler to achieve that. But I found `swapcontext` doesn't atomically set `sigmask` and do a long jump. Instead it firstly call `sigprocmask` and then do a `jmp`(which I think may cause trouble like signal handler reentry). How can I avoid this?

Comment: Is [`sigsetjmp()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigsetjmp.html)/[`siglongjmp()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/siglongjmp.html) a possible solution?  While that wouldn't be *setting* the signal mask, it would be atomically *restoring* it to what it was when `sigsetjmp()` was called.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't know how `siglongjmp` implement it(how does it make restoreing and jump atomaically? Does it rely on any syscall?). Can you explain it?